# getting TimeoutException error on selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I want to collect data from 1 to 5 page from this [page](https://www.usine-digitale.fr/annuaire-start-up). My scraper can go details page of each item but It stopping after scrape 4 or 5 items of page 1 and getting  this error

```
line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message
```

here is my full code:

```
#collect data from 1 to 4 page 
for page_num in range(1,5):
    url = "https://www.usine-digitale.fr/annuaire-start-up/?page={}".format(page_num)
    browser.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)
    # Wait 20 seconds for page to load
    timeout = 20
    try:
      WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[@class="contenu"]')))
    except TimeoutException:
      print("Timed out waiting for page to load")
      browser.quit()

    elements = WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//a[@class="contenu"]')))
    for element in elements:
      #get href
      href = element.get_attribute('href')
      print(href)
      #open new window with specific href
      browser.execute_script("window.open('" +href +"');")
      # switch to new window
      browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[1])
      time.sleep(3)

      #......now you are on the new window, scrape here
      #example to scrape 'title' in the new window
      name = WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//h1[@class="titreFicheStartUp"]')))
      description = WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@itemprop="description"]')))

      print(name.text,description.text)

      browser.close()
      time.sleep(3)
      browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[0])

browser.quit()
```

Comment: I can see that for one of your WebDriverWaits you handle the timeoutexception, but for the others you do not. Have you considered handling those exceptions? It would also be helpful if you point out which line you are having the error on, as line 80 does not tell us much.

Comment: Thnaks for your comments. I am newbie and start leanings python selenium bs4... Can please explain it by code which will help me to understand where I need to be fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that without selenium.Try python `requests` module and `beautifulsoup`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for page_num in range(1,5):
    url='https://www.usine-digitale.fr/annuaire-start-up/?page={}'.format(page_num)
    res=requests.get(url).text
    soup=BeautifulSoup(res,"html.parser")
    for item in soup.find_all('a',class_='contenu'):
      url1="https://www.usine-digitale.fr"+item['href']
      res1=requests.get(url1).text
      soup1=BeautifulSoup(res1,"html.parser")
      print(soup1.find('h1',class_="titreFicheStartUp").text)
      print(soup1.find('div', attrs={"itemprop":"description"}).text)
```

Comment: Thanks KunduK it woked. but can you please tell where was the wrong of my previous code?

Comment: Shall I come back tomorrow on this? It’s late here in UK.

Comment: Okay no problem and I also trying to find why it's not working. See you at tomorrow